# Does iOS Multipeer connectivity work with non-smartphone devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, wifi-direct, multipeer-connectivity

Our guys in the field use equipment that have wifi and Bluetooth connectivity. One of our users has been using a non-iPhone (I guess Android) to transfer files between his phone and  the equipment through Bluetooth. However, in switching our users to iPhones to use other enterprise apps we have discovered what some of you already know: iOS's Bluetooth connectivity is severely limited (i.e. no SPP protocol).

The equipment also communicates via wifi, so I was wondering if it's possible to create an app using iOS Multipeer connectivity to solve the Bluetooth problem. All I am finding about this, though, doesn't show anything but phone-to-phone multipeer connections, and not phone-to-machine multipeer connections.

At this point I know nothing about how the field equipment works; that's something I'll have to learn if we decide to pursue this. But assuming that it is capable of discovering wifi networks, would it be able to see the iPhone's network without needing any special software?

Or would I be wasting my time trying to figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the equipment is using Bluetooth SPP then unless it is MFi certified you can pretty much forget about connecting to it from iOS.  Multipeer connectivity won't do it, that's for sure.

WiFi may be a possibility - you need to get the iPhone and the equipment on the same WiFi network - you can't do this via an app though - you would need to use the WiFi settings in iOS - You will need to learn more about the equipment to see if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. Only iOS 7.0+ or MacOS Yosemite+

MultipeerConnectivity is a framework for iOS and Mac OS. To send data using it, you need  both devices to have iOS or MacOS with MultipeerConnectivity. You don't have any network-related parameters like "I prefer using bluetooth or wi-fi", it was designed to "just work out of box with simple goal - discover and connect other devices with MultipeerConnectivity.
 It means that you can't send data from iPhone with MC to Android or Symbian or old iPhone with iOS <7 etc.

Before iOS7 you could use GameKit, but the logic is the same: both peers need to use GameKit.

If your custom equipment does not have iOS - you need to use lower-level API, and your options include generic Bonjour (NSNetService on iOS device and something Bonjour-compatible on custom device) or CoreBluetooth (obviously bluetooth-only, no wi-fi peer-to-peer) on the lowest level, using sockets and so on.

Comment: I realize I wasn't very clear with my original message, but part of it is that I don't fully understand what I need myself. Since the Bluetooth connection is out, is it possible to instead use a peer-to-peer wifi connection to accomplish the same thing? The equipment of which I speak is not another phone, but it does have wifi connectivity. I'm trying to learn if there is a way, if I need to write an iOS app to do it, to be able to connect to the equipment directly through the wifi, without a router or a network connection. I hope I am making sense. .....And now I've used up all my characters.